# Android OpenGL libraries + software for prepare opengl graphic, practical usage

Tags: android, opengl-es, generator

I would like to use OpenGL graphic on Android games and read some basic tutorial articles. I think it is very difficult, lenghty and long-time taking to prepare OpenGL code by hand. What is the practical way to prepare OpenGL code in real. Are there any editors to generate OpenGL objects code or any software it can help in generating of OpenGL code ? How do the companies prepare OpenGL projects ?

Answer (score 2):

Quick response: Do some research with google for "android 3d engines" and pick the one that meets your needs.

From an opensource perspective, use any open graphics library out there (#andengine #libgdx #shadingzen...) as the main framework so that you don't need to write much of the complex OpenGL code. For creating 3D meshes you can use #Blender which supports many export formats and you can even write your own in python. There are some tons of examples on how to use Wavefront (.obj) objects in OpenGL (e.g. https://github.com/TraxNet/ShadingZen/blob/master/library/src/main/java/org/traxnet/shadingzen/core/shapes/OBJMesh.java).

There is not a OpenGL-code-generating-tool as you may think. OpenGL is an API which allows you to manage GPU driver states which is not enough to display objects, you also need to either write your own 3d engine (even if its very simple) or use any of the already made ones out there.

And again, do some research and find the workflow and the engine that meets your needs.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL is freakingly difficult to learn, for a newbie to Graphics programming. If you are comfortable with Java, then I would recommend you look into LibGDX. The way Libgdx or in fact any other gaming engine works is, they hide the difficulty of OpenGl programming by writing wrappers around OpenGL programs. So if you are comfortable with higher level language such as Java then working in Libgdx is much easier. Then you are good to go about your game.

The reason I have recommended Libgdx is clearly simple,

A) From outside i find they have a very active forum and lot of test code, demos.

B) Also the particle editors from Libgdx is something exceptional from a free Open Source point of view.

C) The ability to verify the output in the desktop is something exceptional, it saves hell lot of time.

It looks like AND engine or cocos2d the other free open source engines are no more as active as earlier. Probably they are having good time in Zynga ville :)